# Closing as duplicate when the existing question is different, but has an answer to the newer question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Given two questions:

- A) An existing question with some answers
- B) A (new) *different* question

Given also that the auto-generated dupe text reads:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
> [Some other question](http://stackoverflow.com) (9 answers)

which can be true even if the duplicate question is a completely different question.

If:

- there is a valid answer to A) that is also a valid answer for B)
- but A and B are asking different questions
- there are other (possibly better) answers to B (that wouldn't answer A)

should B be closed as a dupe of A?

Let me give an example to illustrate:

Question A: "How do I concatenate n copies of a string"?
Question B: "How do I create a stream of n copies of an object and reduce the stream to one final object?

One way to accomplish A is to use a stream of n copies of a string and reduce the stream by joining, which happens to also answer B. So, "This question already has an answer here" would be true.

But clearly the questions are not duplicates of each other, and there are many ways to answer both, so "close as a duplicate" seems inaccurate.

There is a disconnect between the auto-generated message and the questions actually being duplicates. This has led some users to follow the message and close as dupe, despite the two questions not being duplicates.

#### Questions:

Should the question be closed as a dupe anyway?

If not, should the auto-generated text be changed to something more accurate, eg "This question has been asked and answered here", so encourage closing as dupe be done when it's actually a dupe?

---

Update:

The close dialog gives the following description for the "duplicate of" reason:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

So the intention is clear and what I expect from the reason, so can we tune the auto-generated text please?

Answer (score 3):

I think the most important part is this:

> One way to accomplish ... B

If there is (reasonably) just one way to accomplish B, which is the same as with question A, then it should be closed as a duplicate. There is no other option available, there is no possibility more knowledge is added in an answer to the question.

If there is more than one way to accomplish B, and one of them is A, then I am hesitant of closing as a duplicate. There is a good possibility a better fitting answer is given.

As gold tag badge holders and moderators, we have a new option to add multiple close targets when voting to close as duplicate. Maybe a partial answer is given in answer to multiple questions. Then closing as a duplicate of the set is okay as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Huh? You're contradicting yourself. If there are other (possibly better) answers to B (that wouldn't answer A), then once you close it, no more answers can be posted. So, you shouldn't close as dupe, but then you say you should. (But I will add this to the question)

Comment: btw I have met a very high rep user who follows the "there's an answer there" principle and CAD, even if the questions are not dupes, so gold badge etc doesn't mean they get it right. I think it's the text that's throwing him off course.

Comment: If there are better answers possible, I wouldn't vote to close. What part exactly is unclear, I will reword it.

Comment: Even gold tag badge holders aren't always right, they are human too you know ;) If the wording is wrong, they should alter it.

Comment: After re-reading, I retract my "contradiction" quip; you're making sense.

Comment: Actually, I think you've captured the essence of the problem: If there are no other reasonable answers than one found elsewhere, then mathematically it is highly likely that the questions are in fact the same question, but asked in a different way. If more different answers are reasonably possible, especially ones that don't answer A, then don't close. Maybe we should change the text shown to users in the close dialog

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Well the dialog say *This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*, which is pretty clear and how I interpret CAD's intention. The problem then lies with the auto generated text. Can you think of some better wording than my proposal?

Comment: Why the "has been asked before", who cares about that? "This question already has an answer. > HERE"

Comment: Because "has been asked before" means the existing question should be an actual dupe, and I care about that - hence this question.

Comment: But when it is not important the question was asked before, but that the answer is the same, that would mean the question is irrelevant.